# Run function and redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to be able to type `/logout` in the address bar of the browser, and upon submit reset localstorage and redirect the user to `/login`.

I'm imagining something like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/logout">
    {clearAuthInLocalstorage()}
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

How do I correctly declare this with `react-router` in a `Switch` container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Logout` component and in `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook, you can do all the processing

```js
class Logout extends Component {
  state = { loading : true };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    // clear localStorage here 
    this.props.history.push('/login');
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="page">
       <i className="laoder fas fa-spinner fa-spin" />
    </div>
  );
}

<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
  <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
</Switch>
```